# Unused services to disable after a fresh installation?

Tags: installation, services

Are there any services after a fresh ubuntu install, that are probably by most of the standard users not needed, so that you could recommend to disable them?

Comment: Hi! I think that isn't to concrete: "standard user". User who lives net-social life nearly use all installed internet apps, who don't only needs a browser and a text editor(OO). But if you give more details about your standard user, I can say what apps won't you need. But you asked about services, services in desktop version is usually only whitch listed in `Sytstem — > Preferences — > Startup Applications`; ex. **Evolution Alarm Notifier**, what doesn't use a single user, who havent got configured evolution. Questions?

Comment: I can tell from your questions you are in some kind of multi-user environment. Mentioning this would greatly help you to get more accurate answers.

Comment: hi, with "standart user" i mean mostly working with like in an office environment. Writing Documents, Printing, Surfing the web, listen to music and so on. i.e. Bluetooth, Evolution, VNC are not needed at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is highly subjective depending on each user. Most services that start up with the standard `ubuntu-desktop` are in some way required. However, you can disable a number of things which start up for each user in the Startup Applications Preferences, found in System > Preferences > Startup Applications - To disable a program from launching at startup simple uncheck it in the list under the Startup Programs tab.

[image]

Some examples: If you don't use Evolution or, in particular, Evolution Calendars you can disable the Evolution Alarm Notify task. If you do not connect to this machine via VNC or another Remote Desktop tool you can disable the Remote Desktop server application. If your machine doesn't support Bluetooth you can also remove that service. Any service that you know you don't utilize while logged in as your user you can feel free to uncheck.

Comment: :) like my words :D

Comment: As said, it's subjective, but since I don't have bluetooth, when I install Ubuntu that's *the* first thing I disable, then I disable the Evolution calendars & alarms, plus whatever else I feel like experimenting with.

Comment: @BRoland Only difference - I answered 7min before your comment :P Answers > Comments

Comment: where do i find the startup entry for Remote Desktop Tool?